# Nvidia X Server Settings Showing Blank Error

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 14.04, xorg

i'm using ubuntu 14.04 and i have Nvidia GF119M and Intel® Ivybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2 
on me. I tried to switch my card to nvidia, but an error appeared and its blank. How do i get my nvidia to work?

[image: selected driver]
[image: x server settings window]
[image: blank error]

Comment: Can you try to launch `nvidia-setting` through terminal? And see what's the output are?

Comment: Try using `-V` (Verbose, big v) option actually. So, `nvidia-setting -V`. It will gives you more output.

Comment: since there was no reply for like 3 weeks, i decided to reinstall my ubuntu because i had some issues including this. it works fine now. thanks!

Comment: Well, okay, glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since there was no reply for like 3 weeks, i decided to reinstall my ubuntu because i had some issues while trying to fix this. it works fine now.

[image: it works]

looks like i'm missing this part before. sometimes, selecting the nvidia driver itself just gave me a black screen but this one works fine.

[image: select the driver]

switched my driver to nvidia 331 and restart the pc

Comment: p.s. i use `nvidia-prime` and use this ppa `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` to install `prime-indicator` and Install the rest with `sudo apt-get install -f`